# How can I get higher grades in fights?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I'm playing *Batman: Arkham Origins* and one of the tasks for me now is:

*Get at least an A grade in a fight with at least high difficulty*

I tried it a lot, got in a few fights that were *Extreme* difficulty and won it without getting hit(other times just once or twice). But still the max I was getting was *Rank B*. With *Low* difficulty I sometimes manage to get *Rank A* and once I got *Rank S* with one of the predator encounters.

So the question is: how is rank calculated and how can I get at least *Rank A* in a fight with at least *High* difficulty?

Comment: Rank is based on several factors.  How high your hit combo goes until its broken, how many different gadgets you use, how often you use the same gadget, how many times you get hit, how many special combos you activate, how many thugs you hit with a single gadget ( in the case of batarang and the gel ).

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I fought a group of 14 enemies with an "extreme" danger rating, beating them in one continuous combo reaching over 50x and never getting hit, and got a B rating.  Then I nearly threw the controller through my monitor.

Comment: Well, I finally got it after silently taking out a sniper on a roof from behind.  Even though the game said he was a "low threat," it said the task was completed.  This task is definitely bugged...

Answer (score 4):

Merely completing the fight without getting hit is not enough to get a grade higher than B. You need to also use your various gadgets and special moves to complete this task. Doing this is called the "Variation Bonus"

Examples of moves that will increase your Variation Bonus:

- Quickfiring gadgets (using Batarangs, Batclaw, Explosive Gel, etc.)
- Ground Takedown (<kbd>Crouch</kbd> + <kbd>Counter</kbd> on a stunned enemy with stars around his head)
- Unlockable Takedown moves from the upgrade tree
- Other combat moves (Aerial Attack, Glide Kick, etc.)

As long as you use different moves to hit enemies and don't get hit more than once or twice, you should get an A grade. If you complete the fight "perfectly" by using lots of different moves and never losing a combo, you'll get the highest S (apex) grade.

This also goes for predator encounters. Using different ways such as Inverted Takedowns or Tightrope Takedowns to take out enemies will earn you a higher grade and more experience.

Comment: The combo-meter is also taken into account. Just completing the fight with 2-3 hit combos will not get you a high score, even if you perform flawlessly.

Comment: @Chaos_99 I'm not really sure what you mean. If you preform flawlessly then you will have gotten the maximum combo possible (not entirely true as you can get bigger combos depending on gadget use, etc. but what I mean is that you will get just one "perfect" combo

Comment: By flawlessly I just meant 'without receiving a hit'. Even if you use multiple moves/gadgets in a fight and never get hit, you might not reach A grade if you are not able to string your moves together in a (or some) large combo(s). Pausing every few moves and letting the combo meter drop to zero will not net you enough points in the end.

Comment: @Chaos_99 Missing a hit is almost as bad as taking one as far as the game is concerned, except you don't lose health. Losing the combo at any time is not considered flawless

Comment: @Novarg if this answer helped you, please accept it :)